# How to start Virtual Machine by command line in Ubuntu server with VMWare

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, ubuntu-server

I have a server with *Ubuntu 16.04.2* (no UI).

I want to start a Virtual Machine inside this server. In my Windows PC I start it with *VMWare* UI, but I do not know how to do this via command line (I also do not know what packages are required to install in linux to achieve this). Any ideas if this is possible and how?

Answer (score 1):

You should use KVM.

**what is KVM?**

KVM (for Kernel-based Virtual Machine) is a full virtualization solution for Linux on x86 hardware containing virtualization extensions (Intel VT or AMD-V).

Using KVM, one can run multiple virtual machines running unmodified Linux or Windows images. Each virtual machine has private virtualized hardware: a network card, disk, graphics adapter, etc.

The kernel component of KVM is included in mainline Linux, as of 2.6.20.

Ubuntu uses KVM as the back-end virtualization for non-graphic servers and libvirt as its toolkit/API. Libvirt front ends for managing VMs include virt-manager (GUI).

For How to use the KVM on command line, you can refer: http://xmodulo.com/use-kvm-command-line-debian-ubuntu.html

Answer (score -1):

I did not find a way to do this with *VMWare*, but I managed to achieve it with *VirtualBox*. I describe here the steps needed:

**1. Convert from VMWare to VirtualBox image**

Open *VirtualBox*. Create a new Virtual Machine and select to use an existing virtual hard drive disk. Specify the image that works for *VMWare*.
Once the Virtual Machine is ready select *File -> Export Appliance* to export the image as an *ova* file (in my case *benchmark.ova*). The next step is to upload this file to the server.

**2. Install VirtualBox**

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

**3. Start the Virtual Machine**

```
VBoxManage import benchmark.ova
VBoxManage startvm "benchmark" --type headless
```

(you can close it with `VBoxManage controlvm "benchmark" poweroff`)